# Why is the lease of Tulagi Island to a Chinese company concerns the US?

Tags: united-states, china

Excerpts from an article in [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/10/16/world/australia/china-tulagi-solomon-islands-pacific.html):

> Beijing’s ambitions in the South Pacific have economic, political and military ramifications.
>
> The region is rich in natural resources, and China’s investments have provoked worries in the United States and Australia that the projects could give Beijing an opening to establish a military foothold for everything from ships and planes to its own version of the Global Positioning System...
>
> A military installation would carry strategic and symbolic significance. Some American officials believe China’s efforts in the region echo the period before and during World War II, when Japan wrested control of island assets, which were won back in turn by American and Australian troops in bloody battles.

I could not find information on the natural resources within the island and in the surrounding waters. Given its location in the South Pacific, it doesn't seem to hold any potential in affecting trade routes between Europe, Africa and Asia. It may be of military-strategic importance to nearby Australia, but the latter should be more concerned than the US in that case.

Even if assuming that China would be able to build a military station or reach an arrangement with Solomon Islands for stationing of its troops and launches of defense artefacts, how much difference does it make for the US than what China has already done and is doing in the South China Sea?

Comment: That article is, possibly, an on-duty-worry. US cannot do anything with China zone of influence grow in Pacific, so all that left - such articles.